# What is the classical equation of motion of spinning magnetic dipole in a magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, classical-electrodynamics

In short: what is the classical equation of motion of spinning magnetic dipole in a magnetic field?

I can't seem to find this information...

Comment: Did you mean larmor precession? See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/larmor.html

Answer (score 1):

In general the torque $\vec{\tau}$ of a magnetic dipole with magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$ in a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ can be written as

$$ \vec{\tau} = \vec{\mu} \times \vec{B}$$

(see e.g. [here](http://www.physicsinsights.org/force_on_dipole_1.html)).

The equation of motion for an angular motion is defined as

$$\vec{\tau}(t) = I \, \ddot{\theta}(t) \, \vec{e}_\perp$$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $\theta$ the angular displacement. Note that the direction of the torque $\vec{e}_\perp$ is perpendicular to the plain in which the movement takes place. For a general solution you have to express $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{B}$ in terms of $\theta$, in the following I will give you a simple example:

[image: 1]

<sup>[Image source](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/mu/moment.png)</sup>

We assume a constant homogeneous magnetic field $\vec{B}$ in a certain direction and define $\theta(t)$ as the angle between the field $\vec{B}$ and the magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$ (like in the graphic above). Then we simply can express the cross product as

$$\vec{\mu} \times \vec{B} = - \mu \, B \, \sin(\theta) \, \vec{e}_\perp$$

where $\mu = |\vec{\mu}|$ and $B = |\vec{B}|$. We need the minus sign because the  torque operates in the opposite direction of the angular displacement.

Putting this together, we get the equation of motion for the angle $\theta$:

$$ I \, \ddot{\theta}(t) = - \mu \, B \, \sin(\theta(t))$$

which is similar to the equation of motion of a pendulum. For small angles you can use the approximation $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$, which will lead to the equation of motion of a harmonic oscillator which frequency

$$\omega_0 = \sqrt{\frac{\mu B}{I}}$$